# Dependency Injection Error in asp.net core With Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I Have Application Using Microsoft Identity My Models are
Application User

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePic { get; set; }
        public string Birthday { get; set; }
        public bool IsProfileComplete { get; set; }
        public bool Terms { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmployee { get; set; }
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
        public DateTime AccountCreatedOn { get; set; }
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Address> UserAddresses { get; set; }
    }
```

and my context is

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ApplicationUserConfiguration).Assembly);
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(AddressConfigurations).Assembly);
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

My startup File is

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddScoped<ISeedData, SeedData>();
```

i am traying to seed data in program.cs like this

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var seedData = services.GetRequiredService<ISeedData>();
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                await DbInitializer.DataBaseInitialize(seedData, context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("An error occurred while seeding database {Error} {StackTrace} {InnerException} {Source}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException, ex.Source);
            }
        }

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
```

my repository interface is ISeedData and implementation SeedData

private readonly UserManager _userManager;
private readonly RoleManager _roleManager;

```
    public SeedData(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task CreateAdminUser()
    {}
```

but when I run my application I received this error

```
    Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CMS_DataAccessService.IRepository.ISeedData Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CMS_DataAccessService.Repository.SeedData': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[CMS_ModelsServices.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'CMS_DataAccessService.Repository.SeedData'.)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CMS_DataAccessService.IRepository.ISeedData Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CMS_DataAccessService.Repository.SeedData': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[CMS_ModelsServices.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'CMS_DataAccessService.Repository.SeedData'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[CMS_ModelsServices.Models.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'CMS_DataAccessService.Repository.SeedData'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(IEnumerable`1 serviceDescriptors, IServiceProviderEngine engine, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DefaultServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at CMS.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Projects\CMS\CMS\Program.cs:line 24
   at CMS.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: I think I'm mistaken.. I removed that previous comment. I'm thinking that even though it's the same exception, the referenced duplicate is probably not applicable here.  you seem to have registered that type correctly in startup, but attempting to use (resolve types) in services from the `services.ServiceProvider` is really the scope of this question.   presumably, you wouldn't have an issue resolving these types in a controller.

Comment: I could not reproduce this error.  In the `Main` functions scope, it resolves to an instance of `SeedData` (and `context`) using the example constructor using those types.  can you verify that `CMS_ModelsServices.Models.ApplicationUser` is the type referenced and used in your startup file scope.  can you provide the entire `ConfigureServices` scope from your startup file.  can you specify what targetframework you're using (I'm targeting net5), and include dependency package and their versions.

Comment: you can found full code in https://github.com/adelanwer12/CMS

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 `ApplicationUser` types in your codebase.

the one you're registering for Dependency Injection is `CMS_DataServices.Models.ApplicationUser`

[image]

Where as the one used in `SeedData` constructor is `CMS_ModelsServices.Models.ApplicationUser`

to resolve, just ensure the same type is used in both respects.

```
services.AddIdentity<CMS_ModelsServices.Models.ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddScoped<ISeedData, SeedData>();
```